# Creating "save as" or "open" pop-up window link in react for app stored documents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, pdf, popup

I simply want to create a link with default (?) browser window popup which gives user an option to open or download a pdf document stored in application.

Something like this : [image]

I have a "documents" folder in src which contains "example.pdf" file.

And a simple link like this :

```
                <Link
                  href={require('src/documents/example.pdf')}
                  download='example.pdf'
                >
                  Example file
                </Link>
```

Attribute "download" will force browser to directly download a file, or i can add target="blank" in order to view directly in browser, and both solutions works, but i want user to decide if he wants to open a file in browser or download it as in image above.

I know there is a Content-Disposition atrribute, but as far as i understand its for serwer side in order to create a header ? Its possible to use it in front-end side like jsx/html attribute (prop) ?

What is the simplest solution to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is, sadly, you can't manipulate the native browser handling in this way. Each browser has different behaviour, and this is a UX choice from the browser vendor that can not be overridden. In chrome for example, the "run" button only shows if its an executable.

I'd suggest implementing it in userland, i.e. a modal in your react application with 2 links to download or view in browser.